# Visual Studio 2022 Pro Github Copilot - doesn't exist, and we were unable to create it, does not correspond to any known installation root location

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vsix, github-copilot

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2022 Professional Github Copilot extension, and installation is failing.  I do not have ARM64, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216866/cannot-install-github-copilot-on-visual-studio-2022) is not applicable to me.  The installation logs are failing to find folders that for sure exist, including `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions` ("it doesn't exist, and we were unable to create it") and `C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WCF CONNECTED SERVICE` ("does not correspond to any known installation root location").  Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Microsoft, the answer was that Visual Studio was looking for version 4.1.4.0 of System.Numerics.Vectors, and it wasn't installed in my GAC.  Installing v4.5.0 of System.Numerics.Vectors installed it to the 4.1.4.0 path in my GAC automatically; since then, my extensions are working again.  (FWIW v4.1.4.0 of System.Numerics.Vectors is not available from NuGet, so v4.5.0 was the only one available; for some reason v4.5.0 installs to the 4.1.4.0 path.)

Comment: @ChrisF i would like to close this ticket and keep the others, but now that you have linked as duplicate and deleted the others, I cannot close this ticket.