# Unable to Install Any Visual Studio Extensions - Skipping path as it doesn't exist, and we were unable to create it / known installation root location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am unable to install any Visual Studio extensions, whether from the Extensions menu or from the VSIX installer.  My logs are the same every time:

> Skipping 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions' as it doesn't exist, and we were unable to create it

Obviously, this path does exist, but somehow the VSIX installer is not able to access it.

I also get corresponding errors:

> Attempt 0 of 5. Error: 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WCF CONNECTED SERVICE' does not correspond to any known installation root location.

This began after [trying to install the Github Copilot Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153164/visual-studio-2022-pro-github-copilot-doesnt-exist-and-we-were-unable-to-cre), but now all my extensions are broken.

I have tried running VSIX as administrator, downloading VSIX and installing from path, doing a repair installation of Visual Studio, and nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried using the "repair" feature in the VS installer? If that still doesn't help, please use the Help | Send Feedback | Report a Problem feature in VS and attach logs. If you link the ticket here I can help route it internally to the setup team. Thanks.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I have tried the repair, and unfortunately nothing doing  You are very kind to offer to bump the ticket!  Here it is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-Install-Any-Visual-Studio-Extensio/10458512  This is actually not my ticket, but someone having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that the ticket's been assigned to the relevant team and they are investigating.